# 12.04 Boot goes straight to grub then hangs on black screen, what do I do?

Tags: 12.04, boot

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on a Toshiba Satellite C655. No windows and no windows disk.
Ubuntu worked great for about a month. About a week ago after updating it started freezing, and on boot I would get an error  `/tmp not ready or not present`. Two days ago update manager listed 19 new updates, I let it install and now it will not boot. When I press the `power button` it goes straight to grub. In grub `Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-31-generic` is highlighted, I press enter and I get

```
 Error Target file system doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg
```

. I entered `init= bootarg` and I get Error,

```
/bin/sh: bootarg: not found.
```

Now what do I do?

Comment: There should be a recovery entry in the GRUB menu. Did you try it?

Comment: yes "errors were found while checking the disk drive for /."

Comment: Then I would reboot from a rescue USB stick (or CD) with e.g. Ubuntu or SysRescCD (www.sysresccd.org) on it and run a filesystem check on the hard disk. Assuming the hard drive was formatted with ext4 the tool to run would be `e2fsck`. Make sure the hard disk is not mounted.

Comment: I made a disk with 13.04 and tried to run it, but it wont auto load and I cant find a way to make it boot from the disk.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild one but I have experienced a similar situation with a 13.04 recovering 12.04. Took me ages going round in circles eventually I formatted the Live USB and installed 12.04 - problem disappeared.